# Flex version 2.5.35 or later is required, but this is C:\GnuWin32\bin\flex.exe version 2.5.4

Tags: flex-lexer

Currently while working on a project in windows I realized the need for flex 2.5.35 or later.

```
checking for flex... configure: error: 
*** The installed version of Flex, /c/GnuWin32/bin/flex, is too old to use with PostgreSQL.
*** Flex version 2.5.35 or later is required, but this is C:\GnuWin32\bin\flex.exe version 2.5.4.
```

So to install latest flex I searched on internet and I landed on page https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm  but that also version 2.5.4a.
Can someone provide steps to install flex with version 2.5.35 or later in windows!

Comment: The current version of Flex is 2.6.4 and it already has 6 years.

Comment: But how to install 2.6.4 flex in windows? Do we have link to 2.6.4 just like we have for 2.5.4a in gnuwin32!

Comment: Quick google search tells that gnuwin32 is some dead software that stopped being maintained many years ago. I don't think you should use this one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuWin32

Comment: Ok I understand but how to install flex any other alternative than gnuwin32?

Comment: The Wikipedia page lists some alternatives.